# Does class 'label label-inverse' exist in bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering if the class "label label-inverse" exists in bootstrap 3.0? If not what is the replacement for such a class, is it "label label-default"?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create your own via LESS or SASS. Just copy the existing ones and reverse `color` and `background` and name it **label-succes-inverse** etc.